# Help Identify this Trucking Game from the Early 1980's

Tags: identify-this-game

A user at boardgamegeek.com recently asked for help identifying a game he played as a kid in the early '80s. Usually BGG is able to quickly provide an answer for these types of queries, but his question still remains unanswered after a week. I got permission from that user to post his question here, in the hopes that broader exposure might get him the answer he's looking for.

Here's his question:

> Title: **Can anyone help me find the name of this trucking board game I played back in the 80's?**
>
> I don't remember many details but I do remember the playing pieces had a rubber bottom, kind of like you'd put in the top of a bottle, and there was a truck piece of some sort on top of that. There were cards you'd draw which would determine what your mission was. It would give you the place you had to go to pick up your cargo and when and where it had to be delivered. I remember oranges...you'd have to get them to their destination in time before they spoiled. I played this a lot with my sister when we were kids but for the life of me I cannot find it. I remember the name as "Keep on Truckin'" but web searches for that don't match the game I remember.
>
> Can ANYONE help me out please?

Here's a list of possible answers that have been rejected:

Keep on Truckin' America
Game of the States
Auf Achse
That's Truckin'
Breaker 19
Big Rig 18 Wheeler

[Here's a link to the thread on BGG.](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/27711672#27711672)

Comment: For a second I thought this was going to be [Car Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_Wars)!  Sounds like a cool game though.

Comment: [Thread at BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1897596/) In additional posts the user also noted that he was playing the game in the US in the early 1980s. // also "Black rubber stopper things under the truck piece and also I believe the board was a map of the U.S. with a bunch of black dots connected by black lines." & " Regarding the board, what I remember is it was yellowish with lots of black dots connected by black lines."

Comment: Thought I found it with "Big Rig 18 Wheeler", but that's also been rejected in the BGG thread...

Comment: Is it possible for you to add information on why those possible answers are rejected? I mean it would help a lot in answering this question, I think.

Answer (score -1):

The one that I am thinking of is called "The Trucking Game". Came in a white cardboard box. My dad (a trucker) bought it at a truck stop, and told me it was made by a trucker. I remember you had to get a "promissory" note for your truck which ranged from $6,000-$10,000 and had to pay that off and get to your "home" to win the game. I remember if you hit the black X on the board you had to pick a card that gave you fines or made you lose a turn for being overweight, behind on log books, etc. I would love to be able to find another copy of this game.

Answer (score -4):

That’s Truckin’: The Original Trucking Game

https://www.dogbotz.com/products.asp?product_id=974

Product Description:
This rare vintage board game that focuses on how to make big bucks driving big rigs and delivering precious cargoes was manufactured in 1976 by Showker, Inc. That’s Truckin’: The Original Trucking Game offers fun, excitement and danger to its players. The objective of the game is for each player to make deliveries of freight until his/her truck is completely paid for. The first trucker to accomplish this goal wins.

Comment: The question notes that *That's Truckin'* has already been suggested and rejected.